# use iptables's nat to proxy mysql

Tags: iptables, nat, dnat

I find this similar thread but don't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864854/forwarding-mysql-connection-with-iptables-and-differents-network-interfaces?rq=1

My environment as follows:

- **Computer A** has two network interfaces: eth0 `192.168.42.67` and eth1 `192.168.110.2`, with MySQL client installed, selinux disabled.
- **Computer B** has only one network interface: eth0 `192.168.110.4`, with MySQL Server installed, iptables stopped, selinux disabled.

On Computer A , I use command `mysql -h192.168.110.4 -uroot -p` connect to MySQL on Computer B successfully.

Computer A's `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` looks as follows:

```
[root@net ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/iptables  
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Jun  9 20:25:07 2014  
*filter  
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]  
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:140]  
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT  
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
COMMIT  
# Completed on Mon Jun  9 20:25:07 2014  
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Mon Jun  9 20:25:07 2014  
*nat  
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]  
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]  
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]  
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j LOG --log-prefix "REX_NAT_PRE2:"  
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.110.4:3306  
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.110.4/32 -j MASQUERADE  
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j LOG --log-prefix "REX_NAT_POST:"  
COMMIT
```

NOTE:  I set default policy for every chain to `ACCEPT`.

I hope i can use `mysql -h192.168.42.67 -uroot -p` on Computer A to manipulate Computer B's MySQL

I have also executed `modprobe iptable_nat` and `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: can you connect using that rules?

Comment: @c4f4t0r, what did your suggest?

Comment: the answer to my question is yes or not?

Comment: @c4f4t0r, no, i can't , i add Log module to iptables, it indicate the packet after prerouting , source is '192.168.42.67 ' and destination is '192.168.110.4', it is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this rule

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.110.4/32 -j MASQUERADE
```

to

```
-A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.110.4/32 --dport 3306 -j MASQUERADE
```

This would be enough with other rules you have specified.

Comment: yes, it works, thank you , it buzzled me so long!!! can you explain why it works or suggest me some stuff to read ?

Comment: Yes, sure. 

It works because you need to NAT packets which are going TO 192.168.110.4, so it's destination address. You could solve it without NAT, just adding routes on computers C and computer B.

To understand how it works you need to understand how routing decisions being made and how network works.

You can read Computer Networks (5th Edition) by Andrew Tanenbaum. Also "man iptables" will describe syntax of iptables and provide additional info about chains and how packets are proceed.

Comment: Also please mark answer as "Answered" if it solves your issue:) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PREROUTING` rules do not apply to packets from **A**, because `PREROUTING` is only applied to forwarded packets and not to locally generated packets. Instead you can use the `OUTPUT` chain, which is for locally generated packets.

For both `PREROUTING` and `OUTPUT` I recommend that you add `-d 192.168.42.67` to the `DNAT` rule, such that it doesn't match packets it wasn't intended to match.

Additionally, I recommend that you add `-o eth0` or `-o eth1` to the `MASQUERADE` rule in the `POSTROUTING` chain, such that it doesn't match packets it wasn't intended to match.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i use a third computer C `192.168.42.77`,  i can't use `mysql -h192.168.42.67-uroot -p` to connect MySQL yet, can you give me some tips?

Comment: @lost_in Yes, please edit your question so that _all_ the necessary details are present.